# Two Sum Leetcode

Tags: javascript

I wrote the code, but for some reason it displays the index 1, 2, 3, while 3 + 4 will in no way be equal to target (6).

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
   let sum = [];
   var n = 2;

    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
       for(let a = 1; a < nums.length; a++) {
           if(nums[i] + nums[a] == target) {
               sum.push(i);
               sum.push(a);
           }
       }
   } 
   let unique = sum.filter((e, i) => sum.indexOf(e) === i )
   return unique/* .slice(0, n); */
};
console.log(twoSum([1,3,4,2],6))
```

Input
[1,3,4,2]
6

Output
[1,2]

Expected
[2,3]

Comment: I'm guessing you want to find number pairs from the array that sum up to some other number. In that case, the inner loop should start at i+1, not 1

Comment: @Thanks for the help! But I can't figure out what is the difference between starting the loop at 1 and i + 1?

Comment: If you always start at `a = 1` for every value of `i`, the indices will overlap. Eventually, both `i` and `a` will be `1` and two 3's will be added because they sum up to 6. Always starting `a` at `i+1` makes sure you don't sum numbers with themselves and still covers all combinations.

Comment: @DustInCompetent Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, start the inner loop at `a = i + 1` to avoid summing numbers with themselves as well as to avoid checking the same combination twice, e.g (1, 2) and (2, 1):

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let sum = [];
    let n = 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let a = i + 1; a < nums.length; a++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[a] === target) {
                sum.push(i);
                sum.push(a);
            }
        }
    } 
    let unique = sum.filter((e, i) => sum.indexOf(e) === i )
    return unique/* .slice(0, n); */
};
```